# Django - Haystack Query Serialization

Tags: python, django, json, serialization, django-haystack

I'm trying to serialize a HayStack `SearchQuerySet`:

```
from django.core import serializers
serializers.serialize("json", SearchQuerySet().filter(content=request.GET['q']))
```

but it throws:

> 'SearchQuery' object has no attribute '_build_query'

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had faced a similar problem.
used something like this and it worked:

`serializers.serialize("json", [x.object for x in queryset]`

Answer (score 9):

I don't recommend call 'object' per result as it would hit to database and beat purpose of search performance. Instead consider calling [get_stored_fields](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchresult_api.html#get-stored-fields) method which can be used with json dumps:

```
import simplejson as json
data = map(lambda x: x.get_stored_fields(), search_result)
json.dumps(data)
```